# basic java programming with methods

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hey {



public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print(num);
    System.out.println();
    boolean result = shouldProcess(num);
    processInput(result, num); // passing the result and num

}

public static boolean shouldProcess(int n) 
{
    if (n>=6 && n<12)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    } 
}

public static void processInput(boolean result2, int num) // added int num argument
{
    if (result2 == true)
    {

            int sum = 0; 
            for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++)
            {
                  sum +=i;
            }
            System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + num+ " is: " +sum); 

    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Number is outside of acceptable range");
    }
}  
}
```

this code returns a boolean value in shouldProcess, if the number given is inbetween 6 and 12(inclusive) it returns true, if not then false. Then i have made the method processInput which uses shouldProcess to determine if it can compute and output the sum(only if the method shouldProcess returns true. The method to find the sum is called findSum. So I am not quite sure how to take the following block and make this findSum method in my code:

```
public static void processInput(boolean result2, int num) 
{
    if (result2 == true)
    {

            int sum = 0; 
            for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++)
            {
                  sum +=i;
            }
            System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + num+ " is: " +sum); 

    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Number is outside of acceptable range");
    }
```

Comment: But you are already building a sum?

Comment: how do i take that sum out and make it its own method called findSum following processInput

Comment: shouldProcess is not inclusive. You are saying less than 12 instead of <=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (result2 == true)
{

        int sum = 0; 
        for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++)
        {
              sum +=i;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + num+ " is: " +sum); 

}
```

Will be:

```
if (result2 == true)
{

        System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + num+ " is: " +findSum(num)); 

}
```

and

```
public static int findSum(num){
     int sum = 0;
     for( int i = 1; i <= num; i++ ){ sum+= i; } // usually I'll use int i = 0 and add an offset in the loop.
     return sum;
}
```

By the way: you can shorten your shouldProcess:

```
public static boolean shouldProcess(int n) 
{
    return (n>=6 && n<=12); // both inclusive!
}
```

Comment: where do i put in the public static int findSum(num) edit to?